# Type casting operator

Tags: swift, types, casting

In Swift guide that as published on ibooks, as! operator was not mentioned. But in online reference and in some example code, they (i mean Apple in both cases) used as! operator.

Is there a difference between as and as! operators?  If there are, can you explain please?

edit: Im so tired that i wrongly typed "is", instead of "as". That is now corrected...

Comment: Could you point out where exactly they have used it. A link would be great.

Comment: Perhaps you mean `as` and `as!` ? That's documented in the Xcode release notes.

Comment: ah yes sorry about that. Im editing now... @MartinR

Comment: @abdullah i.hizliresim.com/N5z4vg.png, here is a screen shot of two official references. The one at left is online reference, link: developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/… In the example codes given at swift blog (developer.apple.com/swift) they used many times as!

Comment: I was confused as you wrote 'is' and wondered why I never encountered this before and why my playground do not even compile it. :-) That is the reason I asked you for reference.

Comment: My fault, sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

as? will do an optional downcast - meaning if it fails it will return nil
so "Blah" as? Int will return Int? and will be a nil value if it fails or an Int if it does not.

as! forces the downcast attempt and will throw an exception if the cast fails.  Generally you will want to favour the as? downcast

```swift
//ex optional as?
let nine = "9"
if let attemptedNumber = nine as? Int {
  println("It converted to an Int")
}

//ex as!
let notNumber = "foo"
let badAttempt = notNumber as! Int // crash!
```

( You may find that you that an update is sitting there for the swift guide.  It is mentioned for sure in the online version https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html )

Comment: I didn't ask the difference between as? and as operator. Can you look at again please? I asked the difference between " as " and " as! "

Answer (score 0):

operator is the forcefully **unwrapped** optional form of the `as?` operator.   As with any force **unwrapping** though, these risk runtime errors that will crash your app should the unwrapping not succeed.

Further, We should use `as` to upcast if you wish to not write the type on the left side, but it is probably best practice to write it with normal typing as shown above for upcasting.

Example:

You use the `as` keyword to cast data types. [UIWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWindow/rootViewController) `rootViewController` is of type `UIViewController`. You downcast it to `UISplitViewController`.

Another better example can be taken as follows.

```
 var shouldBeButton: UIView = UIButton()
var myButton: UIButton = shouldBeButton as UIButton
```

The `as?` operator returns an optional, and then we use optional binding to assign it to a temporary constant, and then use that in the if condition, like we are doing in the below example.

```
let myControlArray = [UILabel(), UIButton(), UIDatePicker()]

for item in myControlArray
{
    if let myLabel = item as? UILabel
    {
        var storeText = myLabel.text
    }
    else if let someDatePicker = item as? UIDatePicker
    {
        var storeDate = someDatePicker.date
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for typing wrong. Im so tired... 
I wanted to ask the difference between " as " and " as! " . Can you look at again please?

Comment: Here, examples from Apple's references: i.hizliresim.com/N5z4vg.png
The one at left is online reference; and the one at left is ibooks version.

Comment: updated.let me know if you want the answer to be more elaborate.